# std::complex<double> multiplication by other types

Tags: c++

I have the following instructions in C++:

```
std::complex<double> c(1.0, 1.0);
bool b = true;
double a = 1.0;
int f = 1;

double d = a * b;
double e = b * c;  // this operation (bool x complex) is not available    
double g = f * c;  // this operation (int x complex) is not available
```

Observe that the `complex<double>` cannot be multiplied by an `int` not by a `bool` type.

I read somewhere that this was to be solved by the C++ 20 standard. But, in the mean time

**How can I solve this?**

Can I overload something so that the compiler understands these operations?

I do not want to declare everything as a `complex<double>`, and I do not want to program functions to pass arguments because my aim is to use the Armadillo C++ library which uses `complex<double>` for their complex matrices and I want to be able to multiply a complex matrix by a bool matrix. That is why I cannot use functions, but should rather use some kind of class extension / overloading.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647858/multiplying-complex-with-constant-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply provide overloads for `operator*`, like this:

```
double operator*(bool, std::complex<double>);

double operator*(int, std::complex<double>);
```

Obviously, you need to write the definitions as well.

Comment: could you please write the definition of one of them to see how it is done?

Comment: That depends on you really. What does it *mean* to multiply a complex with a bool, such that it returns a double? This solution will only make the compiler happy, but whether the code makes *sense* is up to you.

Comment: to my purpose it would be something like if bool: return complex, else return complex(0, 0), I am more interested in the paraphernalia to make std::complex understand what I want

Comment: Ok, so try writing that. It almost looks like valid code already :)

Comment: Note that `std::complex` has no idea what's happening to it. This is just a way to *use* `std::complex`.

Comment: the thing is that the headers you have posted are not valid. Elaborating on them is this: complex<double> operator*(bool, complex<double>){
    if (bool){
        return complex<double>;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
which is not valid.

Comment: The declarations are fine; they are based on the usage you provided. In the example you just gave, you are trying to return *either* a bool or a `std::complex`. There are ways to do this, but I suggest thinking about *what* you are trying to accomplish, before figuring out *how* to implement it.

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera The code you posted isn't valid because you're trying to use the type names (`bool` and `complex<double>`) in place of variable names.

Comment: I know, I was following the logic proposed by @cigien

Comment: The provided code are merely declarations. In the definitions, the arguments would need names.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
complex<double> operator * (const int & a, const complex<double> & b){
    if (a != 0)
        return complex<double>(b.real() * a, b.imag() * a);
     else
        return complex<double>(0, 0);
}
```

By putting this function around, the compiler understands the operation. Also did the trick with Armadillo C++ matrices.

Comment: Not sure why you check `a != 0` here.

Comment: is it not faster than performing the products by zero?

Comment: It depends, and the difference is probably not significant. If you multiply a lot by zero or a lot by non-zero, it might be faster because of branch prediction. If not, it might be slower because of branch misprediction. And "a lot", here, is difficult to estimate. Plus there are probably other things at play. Anyway, not having the branch makes the code clearer.